# Matlab not able to import from jar in javaclasspath.txt

Tags: matlab, matlab-java

I add `C:/example/myPackage.jar` to my `javaclasspath.txt`. The file shows up at the end of the `javaclasspath` output. However, when I attempt to `import com.example.*`, my subsequent `methodsview` fails. When I `javaaddpath('C:/example/myPackage.jar')`, I get a warning that it is "already specified on static java path", but then my `import` and subsequent `methodsview` works without issue.

I need my jar loaded statically. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being a computer restart. Matlab may not have closed entirely and did not load static jars correctly.